# post back to the same page not working asp.net

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, postback

in my user.aspx page of any particular users account shows all other user names/images as link inside a datalist alongwith the particular users information who is logged in. now i want that if i click any of the other user links the users information should come on the same user.aspx page.   i use this code on page load

```
   Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    If Session("UserName") Is Nothing Then
        Response.Redirect("login.aspx")
    Else
        If Not (IsPostBack) Then
            binddata()
            binddata1()
            binddata2()
        End If
    End If
End Sub


     Sub binddata()
    Dim mycommand As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM details where id = @id", con)
    mycommand.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int)
    mycommand.Parameters("@id").Value = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString("id"))
    con.Open()
    Data.DataSource = mycommand.ExecuteReader
    Data.DataBind()
    con.Close()

End Sub
Sub binddata1()

    Dim mycommand As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM details where id = @id", con)
    mycommand.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int)
    mycommand.Parameters("@id").Value = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString("id"))
    con.Open()
    nameimage.DataSource = mycommand.ExecuteReader
    nameimage.DataBind()
    con.Close()
End Sub
Sub binddata2()

    Dim mycommand As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM details ", con)
    con.Open()
   user.DataSource = mycommand.ExecuteReader
    user.DataBind()
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

and this script for datalist

```
  <asp:DataList ID="custom" runat="server" DataKeyField="Name" RepeatColumns="1" >
          <ItemTemplate>
          <div><table>
             <tr><asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#   GetImageURL(Eval("Pic")) %>' PostBackUrl='<%# Eval("id", "user.aspx?id={0}") %>'/></tr>
            <tr><td align="left" valign="top" style="width:90px"><asp:LinkButton ID="name" runat="server" ForeColor="Blue" Text='<%#Container.DataItem("Name")%>'></asp:LinkButton></td></tr>
               </table></div></ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

this code is working fine for first check/click. when i click one of the users it load the details of the user . but after that when i click another user it doesnot load the details of that user. i want to show : a user logged in , then there on his page there are list of other users with images. when i click any of them the details of the particular should be load in proper places. help me with this

Comment: I am not able to know what tou want to achieve and why you want ?

Answer (score 0):

You are checking for a first page load before perform data binding. Remove this check or check for control name that fire postback before it.

Comment: how to do that can you explain about it

Comment: remove `If Not (IsPostBack) Then` check from `Page_Load` sub

Answer (score 0):

Yuriy's answer should work but another approach is to use [CommandArgument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton.commandargument.aspx) instead of PostBackUrl.  You will need to setup an event handler for your DataList [ItemCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.itemcommand.aspx).  The CommandArgument value will be your ID value.  Your event handler will take that ID and bind it to your data display.